# Angular 2: How to use Observable filter

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service that calls the API like this:

```
return this._http
        .post(appSettings.apiUrl + 'SomeController/SomeAction', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
        .timeoutWith(appSettings.maxTimeHttpCalls, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.timeout())))
        .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);
```

Now I want to implement a filter function on that call using `rxjs/add/operator/filter`, but I can't get it to work properly.

This is the approach I have taken:

```
return this._http
        .post(appSettings.apiUrl + 'SomeController/SomeAction', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
        .timeoutWith(appSettings.maxTimeHttpCalls, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.timeout())))
        .filter(response => response.json().data.Type === 5)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);
```

But no matter what I filter on, the `ngFor` loop produces nothing as long as the filter is in there. If I remove it, everything works as expected.

Am I supposed to add the filter before or after the `map`?

Can I filter on the response JSON like that, or do I need to use another syntax?

**Example JSON**

Here's an example of what the response JSON looks like:

```
data: [
    {
        "Type": 5,
        "Description": "Testing",
        "ID": "001525"
    }
]
```

Comment: The most probable explanation is that there the Type field of the data field of the json is not equal to 5. What is the JSON?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whether `filter()` should be before or after `map()` depends on what you want to do.

I guess in your case `map()` should go before `filter()` because you want to first decode data from JSON and then filter it. The way you have it now won't return anything if the condition in `filter()` resolves to `false` because you're using in on the entire `response`. Maybe this is what you're going for...

I don't know what your response structure is but I'd go with something like this which makes more sense:

```
map((response: Response) => response.json().data),
filter(data => data.Type === 5),
```

Edit:

I'd use `concatMap()` with `from()` to transform the array to an Observable stream:

```
pipe(
  map(content => response.json().data),
  concatMap(arr => Observable.from(arr)),
  filter(item => item.Type === 5),
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nu7jL7YsExFJMGpL3YuS?p=preview

Jan 2019: Updated for RxJS 6

Comment: I have added some example JSON. I tried your way with the filter last, and filtering on both `data.Type === 5` and `data.ID === '001525'` but both fail.

Comment: @GlennUtter That's what I thought. `data` is an array of objects but `map((response: Response) => response.json().data)` returns this as one large array which is then passed to filter. So you want to iterate the result and return only Objects where `data.Type === 5`?

Comment: @GlennUtter Than it's a little more complicated. See my updated answer with demo.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have modified my code, but I get `Property 'Type' does not exist on type '{}'` when doing that inside the filter statement.

Comment: @GlennUtter Ok, is that a TypeScript error on compilation? You can use `item['Type']` instead or define proper type in `.filter(item:Whatevertypeitis => ...`

Answer (score 3):

Here another sample based on @martin's answer:

```
  public searchMediData(searchtearm: string) : Observable<MediData[]> 
  {  

    return this.http
               .get(this.url)
               .map(response => { 
                  let data = response.json();
                  let medidata = data as MediData[];
                  return medidata;
                })
                .concatMap(array => Observable.from(array))
                .filter(medi => {
                        let searchTearmUpperCase = searchtearm.toUpperCase();
                        let mediNameUpperCase = medi.Name.toUpperCase();                       
                        return mediNameUpperCase.includes(searchTearmUpperCase);
                 })
                .toArray();
  }
```

Comment: you can just write  .map(response => response.json().data as MediData[]).