# Angular2- Asynchronous nested API calls

Tags: angular, http, angular2-forms, asynchronous-javascript

```
    this.obsData
        .concatMap((vhosts) => this.apiService.findVH(vhosts))
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data.docs[0]
            this.data.Locations.forEach((loc, index) => {
                if (loc.ip=== undefined) {
                    this.apiService.findLocation(loc)
                        .subscribe((data) => {
                            this.data = data.docs[0]
                            this.idIP = this.data.ip;
                            loc.ip== this.idIP ;
                        })
                }
            });

            this.jsonData = this.jsonData.concat(this.data);
        });
```

Here, I'm getting the data from each vhost and concatenating them to a whole array named jsonData that would have all of the locations of each vhost. There is a variable called IP inside a Location and some of them are undefined. This is why I have the if statement to check if they are undefined. If they are indeed undefined, I do a more thorough search inside each Location and get the appropriate IP name. Then I set the loc.ip to the appropriate this.data.IP name. However, the jsonData array concatenates the data without waiting for me to set the undefined ip name since they are asynchronous. How can I make the jsonData wait to concatenate until all the location ips are not undefined?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40100613/495157 (filter instead of foreach/if)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to provide a good answer as your code can't be run as-is. As far as I understood, you could try appending after each iteration, also assuming `jsonData` to be an array:

```
this.jsonData = []; //or however it is initialized

this.obsData
        .concatMap((vhosts) => this.apiService.findVH(vhosts))
        .subscribe((data) => {
            //this.data = data.docs[0]
            let dat = data.docs[0];
            this.data.Locations.forEach((loc, index) => {
                if (loc.ip=== undefined) {
                    this.apiService.findLocation(loc)
                        .subscribe((data) => {
                            //this.data = data.docs[0]
                            dat = data.docs[0]
                            this.idIP = this.data.ip;
                            loc.ip== this.idIP ;
                            this.jsonData.append(dat);
                        })
                } else {
                  this.jsonData.append(dat);
                }
            });


        });
```

Mind you I didn't run this code it's merely as an illustration.