# Angular 4 + RxJS filtering

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to wrap my head around RxJS and I have a question.  To better understand how everything works, I started a new blank Angular 4 application generated with Angular CLI.  In it, I am running the following code:

```js
this.http.get('./src/app/data/products.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .filter((item: any) => {
      let price = parseFloat(item.price);
      return price < 5.0 && price >= 2.5;
    })
    .subscribe((list: Array<ProductModel>) => {
      this.error = '';
      this.products = list;
    },
    error => {
      this.error = error;
    });
```

The problem is that filter receives the whole object as a parameter and I cannot filter the individual items.  Using RxJS in a non-angular solution, I used this code:

```js
let products = Observable.create(observer => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let onLoad = () => {
        let productsList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        observer.next(productsList);
        observer.complete();
    }

    xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad);

    xhr.open('GET', 'products.json');
    xhr.send();

    return () => {
        console.log('cleanup');
        xhr.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
        xhr.abort();
    }
})
.flatMap(Observable.from)
.filter(item => {    
    let price = parseFloat(item.price);
    return price < 5.0 && price >= 2.5;
});

let subscr = products.subscribe(
    product => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = product.product_name + ' ' + product.price;
        list$.appendChild(li);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    },
    () => {
        console.log('complete');
        subscr.unsubscribe();
    }
);
```

The difference here is that I used flatMap, but if I try the same code in the Angular version I get:
**Argument of type '{ (ish: ObservableInput, scheduler?: IScheduler): Observable; (ish: ArrayLike, ...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
  Types of parameters 'scheduler' and 'index' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'IScheduler'.**

I was just wondering why the same scenario produces different results.  Is Angular using a different flavor of RxJS?  What is the most efficient way to filter the results in the Angular version?

Thank you.

Comment: what is that you are trying to do? can you add ,pre explanation or reproduce in a plunker use the starter plunker from this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655795/parsing-json-into-a-angular-2-object/42656722#42656722)

Comment: can you juse use filter avaiable for fitlering array

Comment: invoke `subscribe()` on your GET method right away doesn't make any sense. You need to return Observable and then subscribe on it

Comment: I updated my answer have look, it answer how you can make use of filter function the way you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below i found from one of SO answer : [Angular 2: How to use Observable filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100530/angular-2-how-to-use-observable-filter)

```
.map(content => response.json().data)
.concatMap(arr => Observable.from(arr))
.filter(item => item.Type === 5)
.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

if you do as above than it convert your array back to observable stream and you can apply filter on it.

But i still think better to makse use of filter function of array rather than going for rxjs filter function

---

I do like this , first map response to json , than subscribe and assign value to my object of array and than apply filtering ..

because first you convert your response to proper object type than filtering becomes easy

```
this.http.get('./src/app/data/products.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((list: Array<ProductModel>) => {
      this.error = '';
      this.products = list;
    };
```

once you get object you dont need to user rxJs filter method also, you can use normal array filter method as below

```
this.filterobj = this.object.filter(obj=> obj.property == val);
```

and if in your object price value is already float than you can do this

```
let filterProduct = this.products.
              filter(o=> o.price < 5.0 && o.price >= 2.5);
```

or

```
FilterProduct(element, index, array) { 
     let price = parseFloat(element.price);
     return price < 5.0 && price >= 2.5;
} 

var filterProduct = this.ProductArray.filter(this.FilterProduct);
```

Comment: @PankajParkar - updated answer just remvoed filter method , just used filter function on array of products that will work

Comment: @haifzhan - you are actully subscribing to obsever , than mean you will get chance to assign response to your object , and that will happen only when you get response form server i.e. when you get response back from get method ...

Comment: @haifzhan - you can remove map and use subscribe but point here is to apply filter function on array rather than using rxjs function ...i think in your answer you did same ...

Comment: Thank you.  I am sure that filtering in the map or subscribe would work.  I was just wondering how would this be implemented using the RxJS filter.  Do you know if there is any difference in the performance of both methods?

Comment: @dpdragnev - yes, because filter method of array applied on already received array , where rxjs filter method required to convert received in oberservable and than you can apply filter on it ....so it kind of double work when you apply rxjs filter on array you already received.

Comment: @dpdragnev - if you read carefully rxjs , method applied on streaming data means filter mehtod applied on the data you received which is steaming but in case of http.get you receive array of data in from of json , so if data i already receive than what is point of applying filter method of rx js

Comment: @dpdragnev - whole point is rxjs provide method when you receive data one by one from outer source ....like event

Answer (score 1):

```
getItems(): Observable<any>{   
    this.http.get('./src/app/data/products.json')
        .map(res => {
          const data = res.json();  // your GET returns array
          return data.filter(item => parseFloat(item.price) >= 2.5 && parseFloat(item.price) < 5.0);  // notice this is not Rxjs filter.
        });
}
```

in your component:

```
this.xxxService.getItems()
  .subscribe(item => ...);
```

Comment: you can remove map and use subscribe but point here is to apply filter function on array rather than using rxjs function ...i think in your answer you did same ...

Comment: because rxjs filter is complicate things ..which is not needed in this case

Comment: @PranayRana You're right. It's not Rxjs filter operation as I commented in the code I wrote and What I think is put `getItems()` in Service Class and only subscribe it when needed in Component class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your second implementation works is because of the `from` method. To better understand how this is all working, you first need to understand how `from` works. `from` takes in an iterable and emits each iteration `one at a time`. So for example, if you have

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(res => console.log('onNext: ', res));
```

your output will be

```
// onNext: 1
// onNext: 2
// onNext: 3
```

Now say we add the rxjs `filter` operator. The filter method is applied on each emitted value.

```
Observable.from([1, 2, 3])
    .filter(res => {
        console.log('filter: ', res);
        return res === 3; // we only want items that === 3 to continue to next step in sequence
    })
    .subscribe(res => console.log('onNext: ', res);
```

your output will be

```
// filter: 1
// filter: 2
// filter: 3
// onNext: 3
```

---

In your first implementation you are calling your json, and lets say it returns `[1, 2, 3]`. That entire array is passed to the rxjs `filter` method (Not each iteration). So you are checking your condition `price < 5.0 && price >= 2.5` on the entire array, which you can't do.

The proper solution is to do a js `filter` method on your output

```
this.http.get('/./src/app/data/products.json')
    .map(res => {
        let data = res.json();
        return data.filter((item: any) => {
            let price = parseFloat(item.price);
            return price < 5.0 && price >= 2.5;
        });
    })
    .subscribe(list => {
        this.products = list;
    });
```

TLDR: rxjs `filter` works the same as a native js `filter`, you just have to be aware of how your observable sequences emits so you know which one you should choose.