# Filter geojson TS

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, rxjs, geojson

I work with angular 8. I have a geojson fille in my asset folder :

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [9.15926605,41.38718765]},"properties": {"f":"2A0000212","n":"HOPITAL LOCAL DE BONIFACIO","c":"20169 BONIFACIO","t":"2"}},
    { "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [9.15926605,41.38718765]},"properties": {"f":"2A0003141","n":"ANTENNE DU SMUR  BONIFACIO","c":"20169 BONIFACIO","t":"2"}},
    ...
]}
```

I want filter my geojson data by the properties "t" (with an mat-select-form and NgModel.

for example, filter the json for items that have the property "t" = 2

```
//Component.ts

json;

constructor( private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {this.http.get('assets/es.json').subscribe((json: any) => { this.json = json;});}
```

Comment: The answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40100613/6335049) should help get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: thanks i try to understand the answer^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rxjs operators should filter the way you want:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { filter, flatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

let filteredData = this.http.get('assets/es.json').pipe(
  map(response => JSON.parse(response)),
  flatMap(obj => obj.features),
  filter((feature: any) => feature.properties.t == 2)
);

filteredData.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: thanks.. i test with filter bu i have this error : core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined

Comment: Is there always a 't' in the 'properties' of each item? And does each item have 'properties'?  If not, you could change that line to be filter((feature: any) => feature.properties && feature.properties.t == 2)

Comment: Yes i have always properties and t

Comment: Here is the stackblitz: https://stack59162128.stackblitz.io

If you are getting "Cannot read property 't' of undefined" then one or more of your data records does not have a "properties" attribute or the structure is slightly different.  Play with the filter to make it match the different cases that appear in your data set.